# Unexpected result using Elasticsearch when dash character is involved

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm querying Elasticsearch 2.3 using `django-haystack`, and the query that is executed seems to be the following:

```
'imaging_telescopes:(*\\"FS\\-60\\"*)'
```

An object in my Elasticsearch data has the following value for its property `imaging_telescopes`: `"Takahashi FSQ-106N"`.

This object matches the query, and to me this result is unepected, I wouldn't want it to match.

My assumption is that it matches becasue it contains the letters `FS`, but in my frontend I'm just searching for `"FS-60"`.

How can I modify the query so that it's stricter in looking for objects whose property `imaging_telescopes` exactly contains some text?

Thanks!

EDIT: this is the mapping of the field:

```
"imaging_telescopes": {
  "type": "string",
  "analyzer": "snowball"
}
```

Comment: 2.X is extremely old, unsupported, and you should really look at upgrading. that aside - what is the mapping on that field?

Comment: Hi @MarkWalkom, thanks, yes, this is definitely on my list. I don't understand what you need by mapping, since I use ElasticSearch via django-haystack, so the internals are hidden to me. Can you please elaborate on how I can find out?

Comment: look at `_mapping/INDEXNAME`

Comment: @MarkWalkom thanks, I edited the question, it's at the bottom.